# Curl request from shell

Tags: php, curl

I have simple php script.

```
$url = 'http://test.com/api/images/products/33';
$image_path = '/srv/images/some.jpg';
$key = 'qwerty';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PUT, true); // Un-commet to edit an image
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $key.':');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('image' => '@'.$image_path));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The script works well. I want to convert this code to simple curl shell command.

I tried

```
curl -v -X POST -d image=@/srv/images/some.jpg \
 http://qwerty@test.com/api/images/products/33
```

but error is occured. What is wrong?

Comment: `/path/to/php /path/to/your/script.php` ;-)

Comment: "but error is occured" — **What** error?

Answer (score 0):

you should use `-F` (for `multipart/form-data`) instead of `-d` (which uses `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`):

so this should work:

```
    curl -v -X POST -F image=@/srv/images/some.jpg http://qwerty@test.com/api/images/products/33
```